# Complete resource of Ngô's course notes on Algebraic Groups and Group Schemes

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, algebraic-groups, group-schemes, online-resources

I'm looking for Ngô's M2 course notes on "Groupes algébriques et schémas en groupes".

The Wayback Machine has an incomplete capture [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101115044428/http://www.math.u-psud.fr:80/%7Engo/GR.html). However, it apparently lacks chapter 1, 3, and 5.

I also asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719183), but still got no answer.

Does anyone have the complete file? If so, please help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried emailing Ngo?

Comment: @Nico Yes, and he didn't reply me yet.